# Stored procedure with concurrency control

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, concurrency

I am trying to write a stored procedure as `SELECT` which should make a booking on a rental house.

```sql
create table rental_house
(
    house_id int identity primary key,
    housename varchar(50),
    adress varchar(100),
    weekno int,
    vacant bit
)
```

If the house is vacant it should be booked and an update should be made in the `weekno`.

If the house is Booked, an error code should be written.

There should be concurrency control.

```sql
CREATE PROC Booking
    (@house_id INT,
     @weekno INT, 
     @vacant BIT)
AS
BEGIN TRAN
CREATE PROC Booking

as
begin tran
declare @house_id int
select @house_id = house_id

declare @weekno int
select @weekno = weekno

declare @vacant bit
select @vacant = vacant

if (@house_id = house_id) and (@weekno = weekno) and (@vacant <1)
begin
update vacant
set vacant = 0

commit tran
end
else begin
 rollback
 end
```

Comment: A simple `update ... where house_id = @house_id and vacant = 1` would already ensure concurrency control.

Comment: I tried this and it didn`t work;

Answer (score 2):

A single UPDATE always runs in a transaction, so two sessions attempting the same update will be serialized (one will happen before the other).  So you just need to detect if the booking was already updated as you update it.

One simple way to do that is to filter the update on `vacant = 1` and then check the `@@rowcount` after the update to see if it affected any rows. eg:

```
update Booking set vacant = 0
where house_id = @house_id
  and week_no = @weekno
  and vacant = 1

if @@rowcount = 0
begin
  throw 50001, 'House not vacant for that week', 1;
end
```

If you check `vacant` in a separate query you need an explicit transaction and an `updlock` hint so the session checking on the status acquires and retains a lock that would prevent another session from changing the status eg:

```
begin transaction

declare @vacant bit = 
  (
     select vacant 
     from Booking with (updlock)
     where house_id = @house_id
        and week_no = @weekno
  )

if @vacant = 1
begin
  update Booking set vacant = 0
  where house_id = @house_id
    and week_no = @weekno
  commit transaction
end
else
begin
    rollback
    throw 50001, 'House not vacant for that week', 1;
end
```